# Get the value of a System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, timer

Having a little problem with the windows form timer. Its a very basic question, but I've looked around and cannot seem to find the answer (I probably deserve a slap).

I need to be able to get the value of the timer, whether its elapsed time is greater than an interval of 500ms.

something like

```
Timer.Elapsed >= 500
```

Comment: Not possible. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is what you really want?

Comment: I'm trying to call a function after a 500ms.

Comment: Then you want to listen to the Elapsed event. Timer.Elapsed += tab tab done :)

Comment: If you want to call a function after 500ms have elapsed, then a timer sounds like a good solution. Why not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Interval property of the Timer to the number of milliseconds that you want to trigger on (500 in your example) and add an event handler for the Tick event.

Comment: @Nathan Whilst this might be the best solution to your problem, it bears no relation to the question that you asked. Read your question again and in particular the second paragraph.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If a OP asks a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question, I think you should answer Y not X, and I think called2voyage did a good job of answering Y.

Comment: True sorry I should have asked that instead.

Comment: I agree that the original question was poorly worded. Perhaps in the future, Nathan, you can address what you are actually trying to achieve in the original question (e.g. How can I execute certain code when some time has elapsed?) then explain in your description what methods you have tried (e.g. I have looked for a way of getting the elapsed time of the timer but cannot find any.).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Er, using the notation of the accepted answer in the meta XY Q, this answer tackles X rather than Y. If X is not stated, as was the case in the Q here, then it's hard to expect people to answer X. At the very least one should say, "The answer to Y is ...., but really you need to address X, and you do that like so." Remember that SO is a Q&A site and we are meant to answer first and foremost the question that is asked.

Answer (score 18):

`Timer.Elapsed` isn't a property returning "the elapsed time" - it's an *event* you subscribe to. The idea is that the event fires every so often.

It's not really clear whether you even *want* a `Timer` - perhaps [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is really what you're after?

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do some work here

if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 500)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ridiculous that they don't put something to track the timer time elapsed, but instead create a whole new class to do the same. Lol, microsoft as always complicating what's easy.

Comment: @Liquid: Not really. They've separated two independent bits of functionality: scheduling a callback, and measuring elapsed time. You often want one without the other.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to be able to get the value of the timer, whether its elapsed time is greater than an interval of 500ms.

A timer does not provide an interface that allows you to ascertain how much time has elapsed. The only thing that they do is fire an event when they expire.

You need to record the passage of time using some other mechanism, for example the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

Comment: Isn't it better to store `DateTime.Now` every time you start the timer and then do the math when you need the value?

Comment: @Andrew Why is that better than `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Given that you will need a helper variable anyway, I feel that storing a `struct` is better than instantiating a whole class. I also have *the feeling* that a `Stopwatch` is *doing something* while it's running, although after checking the source code I see it does basically the same as the `DateTime` approach.

Comment: @Andrew I don't see any benefits in what you say there

Comment: In my case I tried both approaches, and I don't find much difference. Furthermore, I need to display the remaining time until the next timer hit, and for that math the `Stopwatch` isn't more helpful either. I'd call it a tie.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this quickly , might have some bugs but give you the general idea

```
Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 500;
timer.Elapsed += (s,a) => {
  MyFunction();
  timer.Stop();
}
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a `Timer`. `Elapsed` is the event that is triggered when it has reached 0.

If you want to listen to when the event has elapsed, register a listen to `Elapsed`. `Interval` is the member to set the time to wait.

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on my discussion with David [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534019/2321042) about `Stopwatch` vs `DateTime`, I decided to post the two approaches (very simplified) for the cases in which you need to get the remaining time, so you can decide which one is better for you:

```
public partial class FormWithStopwatch : Form
{
    private readonly Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    // Auxiliary member to avoid doing TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds repeatedly
    private TimeSpan timerSpan;

    public void TimerStart()
    {
        timerSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval);
        timer.Start();
        sw.Restart();
    }

    public TimeSpan GetRemaining()
    {
        return timerSpan - sw.Elapsed;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your thing
        sw.Restart();
    }
}

public partial class FormWithDateTime : Form
{
    private DateTime timerEnd;

    public void TimerStart()
    {
        timerEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timer.Interval);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public TimeSpan GetRemaining()
    {
        return timerEnd - DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your thing
        timerEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timer.Interval);
    }
}
```

I honestly don't see a big benefit from using the `Stopwatch`. You actually need less lines by using a `DateTime`. Furthermore, the latter seems a tiny bit clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came with a solution of mine which is kinda simple:

1 - Before starting the timer I store the current time in `TotalMillisseconds` (from the `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds`):

```
double _startingTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
```

2 - Everytime the timer ticks, I get the Current Time again, then I use a `double` variable to get the difference between these two:

```
double _currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
double _elapsed = _currentTime - _startingTime;

if(_elapsed >= 500)
{
    MessageBox.Show("As you command, master!");
    _startingTime = _currentTime;
}

if(_currentTime < _startingTime)
    _startingTime = _currentTime;
```

3 - And finally, because the `TotalMilliseconds` will return the number of Milliseconds that have passed since 00:00 (12pm), that means that when it's midnight, the `TotalMilliseconds` will be equal to 0. In this case I just check if the `_currentTime` is lower than the `_startingTime`, and if so, set the `_startingTime` to the `_currentTime`, so that I can calculate again.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an integer that is assigned with 0 and increments with the timer's interval. Put it inside the timer's tick method so that you can indirectly get the time elapsed by that integer